# Moving forum out of the main database

Tags: database, nodes

I have a Drupal 6 site with an increasingly bloated forum. I am wondering whether it is possible I can move the forum out of the main site's database to a new database, possibly hosted in a new server.

So  I guess my question is a special case of distributing a single Drupal database over several servers.

Comment: How big are you considering bloated?  Have you profiled things and pinpointed that the forums are causing performance problems?

Comment: Well, by bloated, I mean over 100K posts. It is the main part of the site that involves a lot of queries/writes, so I guess it is responsible for a lot of mysql load.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have a multidomain setup where forum.yourdomain is your forum installation and www.yourdomain is your main portal. Then you could have a single sign on for both domains.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this but the difficult part is that how the database can be distributed/synchronized?